# Open Source Cloud OS/OS Architecture

Tags: cloud

I want to know that is there any Wiki or information available about any Open Source Cloud OS other than eyeOS or is there any information that can tell me that what is an ideal architecture  for Cloud OS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [web desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_desktop) wikipedia entry has quite a bit of info.